# Is there a way to open the same instance of a react component in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, local-storage

I have a complex react component on my main page. I'm not using redux. On click of a button, I want to open the same instance of the react component with some new props in a new tab. The problem is I'm not sure how to keep them synchronized.

Let us say I have an array in the state of my component and I'm displaying the contents of the array in the component. Now based on the user's input, I will modify the array. I want the updated array to show up in the component which is opened in the new tab as well.

```
class App extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        this.state = {arr = []};
    }

    handleUserInput = arr => {
        //make changes to arr
        this.setState({ arr });
    };


    render(){
        return(
            // code to call this.handleUserInput()
            <button href="/newtab" target="_blank"> </button>
            {arr} //display the array here
            .......
        )
    }
}
```

The scenario goes like this:

1. I will display this component on my main page and there the user can input something to the component based on which the arr in the state of the component will change.
2. When the user clicks on button, the same component should be opened in a new tab where url will be ending with "/newtab".
3. While both the tabs are open, and when the user inputs something to the component on the main page and triggers an update in arr, I want that updated arr to automatically reflect in the component present at "/newtab"

I'm using react routing like this:

```
const routing = (  
    <Router>  
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />  //user inputs something on this instance of App and arr from this App instance will be updated
        <Route exact path="/newtab" component={App additionalProps={additionalProps} />  // I want the updated arr from the App instance on the main page to show up here.
    </Router>  
  )

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I clearly understand that, through this approach of using react-router to open a component in a new tab, I'm essentially opening a new instance of the App component in the new tab and it makes the App component on main page and App component on "/newtab" page completely unrelated.

1. I want to know if there is a way to share the state between these two components which are on different tabs. I'm half-way at implementing a local storage approach.
   (or)
2. Is there is a way to make react-router open the same instance of the App component in a new tab so that there will be only one instance? If this is possible, will there be any problem wanting to pass new props to the component that opens at "/newtab"?
3. Will my problem be solved if I use redux?

Please let me know if I'm unclear anywhere and if I can provide you with more info. Thank you very much.

Comment: "The scenario goes like this:" This is a good start to describe what you want to do. I suggest you reword this to be entirely from the user's point of view. For example, "the user can input something..." is great. Be more details about exactly what the user inputs. (I assume you leave out some details here that you know full well, but didn't share in your post to us.) On the other hand "based on the arr in the state" doesn't describe what the user does. This is about technical details in your code. At this level you should avoid such details. Describe what the user does and sees as a result.

Comment: @roronoa If my answer helped you then please mark it as accepted so that the question can be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding of React is a bit skewed - you cannot open "the same instance" of a component, as components are not rendered to the DOM. Components are converted to HTML elements, so two different pages have two different DOM elements - they can't be shared.

What you're trying to do is share state between two tabs.

React does not support this, a new tab is a new app, it is a totally separate instance.

The only way to share state between two instances of an app that are open in the same browser would be to use third party / external APIs.

For example, you could connect your app to the browser's local storage. This means that both instances of the app would share the same local storage data. Be careful with this as you must not store any sensitive data (i.e. user details, passwords, bank details, access tokens) in local storage as it is susceptible to XSS and other attacks.

There is a [guide here](https://medium.com/@daverivera90/sharing-state-between-browser-tabs-with-redux-68899eb88fb7) on how to do this (the author uses Redux) but I'm sure you don't NEED to use Redux to achieve this.